# Illustrator - Offset Path Outlines thicker after export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, glitch

I'm new to Adobe Illustrator. How do I fix the exported svg file from looking different than the original adobe AI preview window? Specifically lines in the SVG being thicker than AI[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. For some reason the red filoplumes had a stroke on it that wasn't showing up in the adobe preview. Setting that to zero fixed it. Probably a bug

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "in the adobe preview"?  You should really check an SVG in your browser to see if it renders properly.

Comment: It is not a bug if there was a stroke there. Different apps, different file formats, different previews. You need to understand the tools you're working with: they don't always do what you expect they should do.